# Making library from app

Tags: android

I have an app that I need to make a library of it. The app has a Service and the missing part for me is that I have a class that inherits from Application in order to have a singleton.  How can I replace it?
10xs,
Nahum

Answer (score 2):

> How can I replace it?

As someone with "20 years of programming", you already know the answer to this: [use standard Java singletons](http://www.vogella.com/articles/DesignPatternSingleton/article.html).

You are welcome to force apps that use your library to use your custom `Application` subclass, if you prefer. Using an `Application` subclass in general is not an especially flexible solution, since there can only be one, which is why using standard Java singletons is a recommended alternative.

Just be sure that your Java singletons, like your custom `Application` class, do not introduce a memory leak. For example, a Java singleton should not hold onto a `Context` *except* the `Application` object, as any other `Context` should be transient (e.g., an `Activity`).

Of course, even better is to try to avoid custom `Application` classes and singletons altogether, though they are very useful in Android for things like in-memory caches.